# How can I detect if a user is in debugging mode

Tags: android, mobile, appium, appium-android, usb-debugging

Is there any way to detect if a mobile session on my android app is in android USB debugging mode or developer mode, or otherwise running automation via tools such as appium

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
 if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       return "debug";
 }else {
       return "not debug";
 }
```

Depending on what your are doing there may be a better way, just Google Buildconfig.Degug